# What can I do on rewriting JTextFields in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm currently developing a calculator app based on Java Swing. I want to make the GUI myself (My own GUI kit), but I'm having some problems on JTextField. I want to rewrite it, making it more pretty. But the result is not what I want, what can I do? (I've tried to override the method `paintComponent(Graphics g)` but it's not working.)

See the code below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


/**
 * The custom text field of the app. Will be displayed on top of the Panel.
 * Will be used to display user input.
 *
 * @author abc, 2022/2/22
 * @see javax.swing.JTextField
 */
public class MyTextField extends JTextField {

    public MyTextField(String s) {
        setBorder(null);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 50));
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2d.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 20, 20);

    }
}
```

Comment: When doing custom painting and overriding `paintComponent()`, the first call in the `paintComponent()` should be `super.paintComponent(g)`. That aside, "_but it's not working_" is not a very detailed description of what your problem is. Please describe in more detail what's wrong.

Comment: Also: `setForeground(Color.WHITE)` is probably not such a great idea, when the background is also white.

Comment: Please well-define "pretty". What look *exactly* are you trying to achieve, especially that requires overriding a complex component that uses a separate delegate (the Look & Feel) to help create its appearance?

Comment: @maloomeister My background isn't white, sorry for my un-detailed description. The problem is that when I override `paintComponent()`, Swing did do my "drawing", but I didn't see the text in the constructor parameter. I can edit in the text field, but I couldn't see my words written on it, I think that maybe `setForeground()` was not working.

Comment: You don't paint anything but a rounded rectangle. The text is painted by `super.paintComponent(g)`, if you don't call it, you have to paint all the text yourself.